# Can`t get returned boolean value from class function call

Tags: php

I cant get returned value from php function call.

```
            ...
            $dey=$validate->yoxla($this->ad,$this->soyad,$this->istadi,$this->sifre,$this->email);

            if($dey){ // i cant get returned value from here. even it is true.
                echo 'asd';
                if(!$checkuser->checkusername($this->istadi)){
                    $err=array();
                    $err['code']='code14';
                    $err['aciglama']=$code14;
                    print json_encode($err);
                    die();
                }elseif(!$checkuser->checkemail($this->email)){
                    $err=array();
                    $err['code']='code15';
                    $err['aciglama']=$code15;
                    print json_encode($err);
                    die();
                }else{
                    $err=array();
                    $err['code']='acig';
                    print json_encode($err);
                    die();
                }
            }
```

yoxla() function:

```
        ...
        elseif (!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $sifre)){
            $err=array();
            $err['code']='code11';
            $err['aciglama']=$code11;
            print json_encode($err);
            die();
        }elseif($email==""){
            $err=array();
            $err['code']='code12';
            $err['aciglama']=$code12;
            print json_encode($err);
            die();
        }elseif (!$this->validEmail($email)) {
            $err=array();
            $err['code']='code13';
            $err['aciglama']=$code13;
            print json_encode($err);
            die();
        }else{
            return true;
        }
```

I call first one by ajax request. and there is nothing returning to ajax or i cant get returned value from getresult() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove () from From class declaration :

try this :

```
class Form{
   public function getresult(){
       return true;
   }
}

$validate=new Form();    
$result=$validate->getresult();

if($result){ 
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Enable php error logging so that you could understand such errors on browser : http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: you should have posted the right code first time, now the answer doesn't match the question.

Comment: Sory its my fault(

Comment: You could have created a new question because now this answer is invalid. :\